# How to run DISTINCT on non-key in SQL

Tags: android, sql, sqlite

I have a database that can have similar rows, but have different keys and a different boolean column.  Here is what the database looks like:

columns: _id, name, img, address, available

Two entries can look like this:

```
_id | name | img                | address   | available
-------------------------------------------------------
1   | John | http://img.com/222 | 1 Main St | 1
2   | John | http://img.com/222 | 1 Main St | 0
```

I want a query that will give me all results that have a distinct key, and if there are duplicate entries(ignoring the fact that _id would be different), it will give back only the first one.  Here is the query I have:

```
SELECT p1.* 
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT _id, available FROM people) p
    INNER JOIN people p1
    ON p1._id=p._id
ORDER BY p1.available DESC;
```

I know this isn't right, but maybe it explains a little what I am looking for.  Would I want to use GROUP BY here?

Comment: What is your definition of "first one"?  Is it determined by the AVAILABLE column?  Or just random?

Comment: Good question.  Sorry I left that out.  Ideally it will order by 'available' in descending order so that if there are two columns with the same data(aside from _id and available), it will return the row with '1' for the available column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`I want a query that will give me all results that have a distinct key, and if there are duplicate entries(ignoring the fact that _id would be different), it will give back only the first one.....the _id isn't what I want to be distinct, as they [the ids] are already unique. ... . Ideally it will order by 'available' in descending order so that if there are two columns with the same data(aside from _id and available), it will return the row with '1' for the available column`

```
             select name, image, address, max(availability) as avail
              from T
             group by name, image, address
```

Then you can join the set returned by the query above, as an inline view, to your table:

```
            select * from T
            inner join
            (

             select name, image, address, max(availability) avail
              from T
             group by name, image, address
            ) as foo

            on T.name = foo.name and T.image = foo.image and T.address = foo.address and T.availability = foo.avail
```

It would help to have a composite index so:  (name, image, address).

Caveat: if there is more than one row where a specific {name, image, address} triad has availablility =1, the query will return multiple rows for the triad:

```
             2   | John | http://img.com/222 | 1 Main St | 1
             6   | John | http://img.com/222 | 1 Main St | 1
```

P.S. It sounds as though you wished the triad (name, image, address) had been created in your table an alternate UNIQUE key.

Comment: VERY nice!  This was it.  The GROUP BY was the critical piece of information.  With that, I didn't even need the complex inner join, just inner join T._id=foo._id

Comment: @Du3: But there shouldn't be a foo.id since the grouping is by the triad (name, image, address).

Answer (score 0):

this sql may solve your problem:

select b.* from （select distinct _id from people) a, people b where a._id = b._id order by b.available

Comment: Thanks for the try, but this doesn't.  I tried.  I think the problem here is that the _id isn't what I want to be distinct, as they are already unique.  This is taking the same dataset against itself and will always give the same results as select * would give.

Answer (score 0):

I actually just asked a similar question and received a great answer from an experienced user here:

[SQL Populating with distinct data and a sequence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7378338/sql-populating-with-distinct-data-and-a-sequence)

Based on what he told me, perhaps this query would provide you with what you want:

```
SELECT p1.* 
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT _id, name from people) p
   INNER JOIN people p1
   ON p1._id=p._id
ORDER BY p1.available desc
```

apologies if that's a fail and doesn't work!

EDIT: It just occurred to me that I have no idea which distinct name+_id combo this will extract.. the available=1 or the available=0 or a random selection..! Let me know what happens anyway..

Comment: Hey Jacky,
Thanks, this is close, but the problem is that the _id field is different on the two rows, so it will think that each of them are distinct in the inner query.  The _id's and 'available' columns are unique but the other fields are not.  I updated the original to the query I tried.  Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 0):

If you want the first row which has the lowest `_id` among those that have the highest `available` value (between 1 and 0), you can "record" the `_id` inside the aggregated value generated by the grouping.

The value to compare is constructed in a way that orders the record by their `available` field in descending order and then by their `_id` field in descending order, and allow to easily retrieve the value of the `_id` with the modulo operator (assuming available max value is 1 and the ids are never above 100000000).

```
select people.* from people 
inner join ( 
    select name, img, address, 
    min((1-available)*100000000 + _id) avail_id 
    from people group by name, img, address
) as foo on people._id = foo.avail_id % 100000000;
```

I adapted it [Tim's query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7378152/how-to-run-distinct-on-non-key-in-sql/7380076#7380076).

You can also do that [without subquery](http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2007/03/14/how-to-find-the-max-row-per-group-in-sql-without-subqueries/):

```
select people.* from people 
left outer join people as other on 
    other.name = people.name and 
    other.img = people.img and 
    people.address=other.address and 
    (1 - people.available) * 100000000 + people._id > 
        (1 - other.available) * 100000000 + other._id 
where other.available is null;
```