# SQL Populating with distinct data and a sequence

Tags: sql, oracle

My problem is as follows:

- I need to populate a 'cars' table based on information from instances
  of rentals of the cars.
- I need to create a primary key 'car_id' but only for distinct
  registration plates in the rentals table.
- I am creating the car_id with a sequence.

I have tried the following code but receive an error:

```
--INSERT INTO cars c (c.plate, c.car_id)
SELECT DISTINCT cr.plate, car_id_seq.nextval
FROM cars_rentals cr
;
```

Although this will work (without distinct registration plates):

```
--INSERT INTO cars c (c.plate, c.car_id)
SELECT cr.plate, car_id_seq.nextval
FROM cars_rentals cr
;
```

(The top line is commented so I can see the values I'm trying to output straight away)

So! Does anyone know how I can either; A) Get the above code to work with DISTINCT or B) find a way to get MAXVALUE of the sequence as the DISTINCT COUNT of the registration plates (so I can do two insert statements)

Thanks in advance!
Jack

Comment: Presumably the error was `ORA-02287: sequence number not allowed here`?  It's generally best to say.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The error is:

> ORA-02287: sequence number not allowed here

This will resolve it:

```
SELECT cr.plate, car_id_seq.nextval
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT plate FROM cars_rentals) cr
```

Comment: Tony you legend! I didn't know you could nest subqueries inside the FROM clause :O:O My world just got flipped upside down. Thanks a lot! (and yes that was the error, sorry for omitting it)

Answer (score -2):

Try this

```
select cr.plate,max(car_id_seq.nextval)
from car_rentals cr
group by cr.plate
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but this didn't work I'm afraid as I don't think you can take a max value from a sequence! cheers tho

Comment: Try casting the sequence as am integer